# Pythonic way of multiple for loops that create new lists on each iteration, and also clean data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

I am pretty new to Python (using 3.5 with Anaconda)--with previous experience in MATLAB. Your help is much appreciated. If there's an easier way to do this, please let me know.

I have data that I read and cleaned from a pdf file from some experimental equipment and appended together into a list:

```
>print(outputdata)

[[['2.37701'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['18.95276'], ['5.07365e-1']], [['2.75613'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['16.99642'], ['4.10023e-1']], [['1.80527'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['20.75384'], ['4.58238e-1']], [['1.58721'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['18.06942'], ['3.81128e-1']], [['1.98336'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['18.20776'], ['3.64733e-1']], [['1.75710'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['23.03760'], ['4.36234e-1']], [['1.58967'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['21.43884'], ['3.88509e-1']], [['2.37701'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['-'], ['18.95276'], ['5.07365e-1']]]
```

I am trying to take the each element from every element of the list and save this into a new list. I also want to clean the data to remove the brackets and quotes and keep the number. I will need to do operations on this so I planned on converting to a numpy array, and then adding that to a DataFrame to export to Excel easier (I have the code for exporting already). Each column vector corresponds to a particular heading:

```
Molecule = ["H2", "Ar", "Methane", "Ethane", "Ethylene", "Propane(C3H8)", "Propylene"]
```

Here is an example of desired H2 data:

```
2.37701
2.75613
1.80527
1.58721
1.98336
1.75710
1.58967
2.37701
```

I accomplished this first doing:

```
outputdatalist = [x[0] for x in outputdata]
```

which had the following output:

```
[['2.37701'], ['2.75613'], ['1.80527'], ['1.58721'], ['1.98336'], ['1.75710'], ['1.58967'], ['2.37701']]
```

and then

```
for row in outputdatalist:
    print(' '.join(row))  # I need to append this on every iteration
```

My unpythonic (and unsuccessful) way of doing this was to do a double (triple?) for loop as follows:

```
outputdatalist = []
for counter, elem in enumerate(Molecule):
for counter1, elem1 in enumerate(outputdata):
     outputdatalist[counter] = [x[counter1] for x in outputdata]
```

And then afterwards convert each outputdatalist[i] to np array and then loop through a pd.Dataframe with something like

```
pd.DataFrame({Molecule[i]: outputdatalist[i]})
```

Comment: Why not: `[x[0][0] for x in output_data]` to get your "desired H2" data? What are you doing after you say "My unpythonic (and unsuccessful)..."? `Molecule` comes out of nowhere.

Comment: Each element of Molecule corresponds to a column of data. MaxU has the right output that I am looking for below.

Comment: In case anyone is interested. The information is exported to excel's cells as text. To get to number format, I had to first change the hyphens to zeros as follows:

    page_remove_spaces = [i.replace('-', '0') if i == '-' else i for i in page_remove_spaces]

and then convert the strings to floats:

    df = df.astype(float)

prior to exporting to Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nested list comprehension`, what seems faster as solution with `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[y[0] for y in x] for x in outputdata], columns=Molecule)
print (df)
        H2 Ar Methane Ethane Ethylene Propane(C3H8)   Propylene
0  2.37701  -       -      -        -      18.95276  5.07365e-1
1  2.75613  -       -      -        -      16.99642  4.10023e-1
2  1.80527  -       -      -        -      20.75384  4.58238e-1
3  1.58721  -       -      -        -      18.06942  3.81128e-1
4  1.98336  -       -      -        -      18.20776  3.64733e-1
5  1.75710  -       -      -        -      23.03760  4.36234e-1
6  1.58967  -       -      -        -      21.43884  3.88509e-1
7  2.37701  -       -      -        -      18.95276  5.07365e-1
```

**Timings**: (small Dataframe)

```
In [21]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([[y[0] for y in x] for x in outputdata], columns=Molecule)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(outputdata, columns=Molecule).apply(lambda x: x.str[0]))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.59 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome solution as well. Thanks! I wish I could accept both answers, but I went with this one because of the added speed indication. I will look more into this.